# Can a university prevent me from choosing any elective module (subject)?

Tags: masters, university, policy

I am a student in an Irish university and I will be going into my fourth year in September. My problem is that I would like to apply for a MSc programme, for which one of the requirements is previous enrollment in mathematics modules, but, unfortunately, my course did not offer any classes in maths. I would like to choose mathematics as a part of my elective subjects, but administrators in my school told me that I am not allowed to do that, since mathematics is not in a domain of my course. I looked up college policies and none of them specifically mentioned that I cannot do that. Though, they indicate that:

1. The selection of the module depends on the lecturer and the school concerned. The student is allowed to choose a module provided they are capable of profiting by attendance thereat.
2. Some schools explicitly point out that if a student wishes to enroll in a module not allowed by the regulations they must make an application to the college.

My question is: is it worth arguing with the college administrators to make an exception or should I just accept that I am simply not allowed to do that. I think they rationale is that no-one ever made such a request and that it could become a precedent.

Comment: I can imagine some math courses being filled to capacity, and thus not allowing outsiders to enroll.  And I can imagine a student who has done no math for four years not being able to keep up in a math course.  But of course neither of these answers your question.

Comment: There is a big difference between not allowing you to take an extra module, not counting the module towards your degree, and preventing from taking a module all together. When exactly did they say?

Comment: Have you checked the timetables? I could see having conflicts between the courses and/or exams because most students don't take this combination.

Comment: The problem is of a practical nature: we have a limited number of electives to select from. I CAN choose an additional module (with a fee obviously), but it clashes with with the aforementioned electives. I was wondering if I could swap a regular elective available for my course with a mathematics module, but apparently it is not possible. The only possibility for me seems to be deferring the application for the MSc programme until next year when I will be able to take those additional classes.